# Change color of SVG background-image (Bootstrap 4 carousel)

Tags: css, svg, background-image, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

I have a BS 4 carousel with next/prev controls which works so far. I have a light background so I would like to change the color of the controls (currently white).

HTML:

```
<div id="carouselQuotes" class="carousel slide quotecaru" data-ride="carousel">
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carouselQuotes" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselQuotes" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselQuotes" data-slide-to="2"></li>
</ol>
<div class="carousel-inner">
    ... carousel items ...
</div>
<a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselQuotes" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
</a>
<a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselQuotes" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
</a>
```

Changing the color of the indicators was easy since that's simply set with a colour as their background. But setting background-color or color for the prev/next controls didn't change the color of the actual control icon.

I found that the icons are set via background-image SVG. There is a part of it stating the fill color:

```
.carousel-control-prev-icon {
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' fill='%23fff' viewBox='0 0 8 8'%3E%3Cpath d='M5.25 0l-4 4 4 4 1.5-1.5-2.5-2.5 2.5-2.5-1.5-1.5z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}
```

I tried

```
.carousel-control-prev-icon, .carousel-control-next-icon {
    fill: #000;
}
.carousel-control-prev-icon, .carousel-control-next-icon {
    fill: '#000';
}
.carousel-control-prev-icon, .carousel-control-next-icon {
    fill: '%23000';
}
```

Is there a way to change the color of the icon without overriding the entire background-image line?

Thank you

Answer (score 28):

You can't style the contents of that SVG background image using CSS rules.  It is parsed and processed and effectively turned into a bitmap image as it's decoded.

You would need to alter the SVG itself.  Change the

```
fill='%23fff'
```

to

```
fill='%23000'
```

or to whichever colour you wish.  The "%23" here is just the "#" symbol. It needs to be [URL-encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) when used in a Data URI like this.

```css
div {
  background-color: black;
}

button {
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  border: none;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.carousel-control-prev-icon {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' fill='%23fff' viewBox='0 0 8 8'%3E%3Cpath d='M5.25 0l-4 4 4 4 1.5-1.5-2.5-2.5 2.5-2.5-1.5-1.5z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}


div.inverted {
  background-color: white;
}

.inverted .carousel-control-prev-icon {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' fill='%23000' viewBox='0 0 8 8'%3E%3Cpath d='M5.25 0l-4 4 4 4 1.5-1.5-2.5-2.5 2.5-2.5-1.5-1.5z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></button>
</div>

<div class="inverted">
  <button class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change color of SVG background-image

```
  .carousel-control-prev-icon {
        background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' fill='%23ff0000' width='8' height='8' viewBox='0 0 8 8'%3e%3cpath d='M5.25 0l-4 4 4 4 1.5-1.5L4.25 4l2.5-2.5L5.25 0z'/%3e%3c/svg%3e");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

for bootstrap 5 you have to do it like this
suppose you have svg with defaults

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="300" height="300" fill="#00ff00" class="bi bi-check-circle" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
<svg>
```

change fill to
`fill="#00ff00"` for green
`fill="#000000"` for black etc.
you can read the hex code from internet

Answer (score 0):

I did it like this

- copied hexa decimal code from google for example #A569BD
- used url encoder online https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/
- it encoded Hexa code #A569BD to  %23A569BD
- I used encoded code in svg to fill elements like this

[image]