# Centering and reducing size of a image in Bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap-4

I tried to follow the answer of another similar question here, at Stack Overflow, but the solutions didn't work for me. I'm working in Ubuntu, Bootstrap 4.0 and coding at atom. How I'm adding the image is pretty basic, it's the following code:

```
<img src="x.png">
```

I tried with the following solutions to center the image:

```
<img src="x.png" class="img-responsive center-block">
```

and

```
<img class="mx-auto d-block" src="x.png">
```

Also creating a new class:

```
.img-center {margin:0 auto;}
```

And trying

```
 <img src="x.png" class="img-responsive img-center">
```

In other hand, I did have not much luck trying to reduce the size of the image, so any hint would be welcome.

Comment: You probably didn't have much luck because you made no attempt to modify either the `height` or the `width` of the image. Though your question is very unclear as it stands. Please clearly state **exactly** what you're trying to achieve, and showcase what you currently have in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I tried to modify the height and width with no much success, if I put everything what I tried I think won't be much readable for the people. I'm trying to be the most minimalist and complete with the information. If do you think I've to add something more, please add another comment. Thank you :)

Comment: The code you currently have in your question is totally useless. What you need to post is a [mcve]. Read that page a couple of times from start to finish.

Comment: That code you posted might be "minimalist" but it's FAR from being a **complete** and **verifiable** example. Not even remotely close!

Comment: Here's what a [mcve] looks like: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49391884/8270343 As you see there, one click of a button immediately shows that the carousel controls are **red** indeed.