# Bootstrap 5 Close Button: Easy way to change color?

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

With the release of v5, Bootstrap has updated the styling of several components, including the [close button](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/close-button/). Before v5, the "x" was text that could be easily styled, including inheriting color from a parent. Now however, the button is styled using a background SVG image:

```
.btn-close {
  box-sizing: content-box;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  padding: .25em .25em;
  color: #000;
  background: transparent url(data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 16 16' fill='%23000'%3e%3cpath d='M.293.293a1 1 0 011.414 0L8 6.586 14.293.293a1 1 0 111.414 1.414L9.414 8l6.293 6.293a1 1 0 01-1.414 1.414L8 9.414l-6.293 6.293a1 1 0 01-1.414-1.414L6.586 8 .293 1.707a1 1 0 010-1.414z'/%3e%3c/svg%3e) center/1em auto no-repeat;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: .25rem;
  opacity: .5;
}
```

In terms of adjusting the color, there's a `.btn-close-white` [variant](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/close-button/#white-variant) that inverts the color using a CSS filter, but I want a specific color. When including the raw SCSS files, you can update the `$btn-close-color` variable to change the color. However, I'm using Bootstrap in an environment where we include the CSS as a stylesheet link, so I can't update the SCSS.

I'd like to easily change the color of the "X", ideally in a relatively flexible way like before where color can be inherited. [Some answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47122852/change-color-of-svg-background-image-bootstrap-4-carousel) I've found suggest that the background image cannot be styled with CSS. I've tried using [CSS filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42966641/how-to-transform-black-into-any-given-color-using-only-css-filters), but have found it pretty difficult to specify a specific color. Are there any other approaches I can use? Thanks!

Comment: How about ditching the background image and instead introducing a character as content on a pseudo element?

Comment: Sure, I could do that but then I'm basically just bypassing Bootstrap and creating my own component. I was hoping there might be a way to work with the Bootstrap files but modify the image color.

Answer (score 6):

Not sure if this was answered but per Bootstrap try this:

```
<button type="button" class="btn-close btn-close-white" aria-label="Close"></button>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: this class is an "alternative" for dark mode. and in 5.3 it become deprecated. need to use `data-bs-theme="dark"` attribute for the same effect. more details here - https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/migration/#close-button

Answer (score 5):

You could either use a [tool like this](https://codepen.io/sosuke/pen/Pjoqqp) to create a specific color filter, OR change the fill color in the SVG...

```
.btn-close-yellow {
  background: transparent url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 16 16' fill='%23fc0'%3e%3cpath d='M.293.293a1 1 0 011.414 0L8 6.586 14.293.293a1 1 0 111.414 1.414L9.414 8l6.293 6.293a1 1 0 01-1.414 1.414L8 9.414l-6.293 6.293a1 1 0 01-1.414-1.414L6.586 8 .293 1.707a1 1 0 010-1.414z'/%3e%3c/svg%3e") center/1em auto no-repeat;
}
```

[Demo](https://codeply.com/p/8ja1aki9fC)

Comment: How do you generate the svg string for a new color, like white for example?

Comment: @Cody you change the 'fill' value with : '%CODE' (where CODE is rgb code of your color)

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the way you're using Bootstrap, you could go and directly change the variable, $btn-close-color: $primary (for example)

Or, if you want to be able to write something like, btn-close-primary in the html, you can make a mixin.

```
    @mixin button-close-color($color) {
     $btn-close-bg:  url("data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 16 16' fill='#{$color}'><path d='M.293.293a1 1 0 011.414 0L8 6.586 14.293.293a1 1 0 111.414 1.414L9.414 8l6.293 6.293a1 1 0 01-1.414 1.414L8 9.414l-6.293 6.293a1 1 0 01-1.414-1.414L6.586 8 .293 1.707a1 1 0 010-1.414z'/></svg>");
     background: transparent escape-svg($btn-close-bg) center / $btn-close-width auto no-repeat;
    }
```

Then loop through the theme

```
@each $color, $value in $theme-colors {
  .btn-close-#{$color} {
    @include button-close-color($value);
  }
}
```

Comment: Or, to style alert box close buttons, `.alert-#{color} .btn-close` as the selector

Answer (score 0):

background: transparent url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 16 16' fill='%23fc0'%3e%3cpath d='M.293.293a1 1 0 011.414 0L8 6.586 14.293.293a1 1 0 111.414 1.414L9.414 8l6.293 6.293a1 1 0 01-1.414 1.414L8 9.414l-6.293 6.293a1 1 0 01-1.414-1.414L6.586 8 .293 1.707a1 1 0 010-1.414z'/%3e%3c/svg%3e") center/1em auto no-repeat;
}

Comment: just paste this and change the fill to fit your color